# Python - regex relation extraction

Tags: python, regex, nltk

As a part of schoolwork we have been given this code:

```
>>> IN = re.compile(r'.*\bin\b(?!\b.+ing)')
>>> for doc in nltk.corpus.ieer.parsed_docs('NYT_19980315'):
...     for rel in nltk.sem.extract_rels('ORG', 'LOC', doc,
...                corpus='ieer', pattern = IN):
...         print(nltk.sem.rtuple(rel))
```

We are asked to try it out with some sentences of our own to see the output, so for this i decided to define a function:

```
def extract(sentence):
    import re
    import nltk

    IN = re.compile(r'.*\bin\b(?!\b.+ing)')
    for rel in nltk.sem.extract_rels('ORG', 'LOC', sentence, corpus='ieer', pattern = IN):
        print(nltk.sem.rtuple(rel))
```

When I try and run this code:

```
>>> from extract import extract
>>> extract("The Whitehouse in Washington")
```

I get the gollowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    extract("The Whitehouse in Washington")
  File "C:/Python34/My Scripts\extract.py", line 6, in extract
    for rel in nltk.sem.extract_rels('ORG', 'LOC', sentence, corpus='ieer', pattern = IN):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\sem\relextract.py", line 216, in extract_rels
    pairs = tree2semi_rel(doc.text) + tree2semi_rel(doc.headline)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong in my function?
The correct output for the test sentence should be:

```
[ORG: 'Whitehouse'] 'in' [LOC: 'Washington']
```

Comment: What does `nltk.corpus.ieer.parsed_docs('NYT_19980315')` return? Is it supposed to be [`nltk.corpus.reader.ieer.parsed_docs()`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.ieer.IEERCorpusReader.parsed_docs)? It looks (based on your code) like it returns a list of objects with `text` attributes, while you're just using strings. Can you create those objects (whatever they are)?

Comment: @KSFT >>> c = nltk.corpus.ieer.parsed_docs('NYT_19980315')
>>> c[1]  returns = <IEERDocument NYT19980315.0064: 'IN CYBERSPACE, IS THERE LAW WHERE THERE IS NO LAND?'>  Apart from that i know as much as you this is all we have been given

Comment: Your `extract` function misses `for doc in nltk.corpus.ieer.parsed_docs('NYT_19980315'):` line. Can it be the problem?

Comment: @stribizhev I believe that line is extracting a number of documents(Strings?) from a corpus, and then these strings are examined to find a relation. However, I want to use my own custom string rather than use ones from the corpus.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the method definition of [extract_rels](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sem/relextract.html), it expects the parsed document as third argument.
And here you are passing the sentence. To overcome this error, you can do following :

```
tagged_sentences = [ nltk.pos_tag(token) for token in tokens]
class doc():
    pass
IN = re.compile(r'.*\bin\b(?!\b.+ing)')
doc.headline=["test headline for sentence"]
for i,sent in enumerate(tagged_sentences):
    doc.text = nltk.ne_chunk(sent)
    for rel in nltk.sem.relextract.extract_rels('ORG', 'LOC', doc, corpus='ieer', pattern=IN):
        print(nltk.sem.rtuple(rel) )// you can change it according
```

Try it out..!!!